# Customize Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am working on an app in which I have implemented Action Bar using Action Bar Sherlock. I have also assigned style to it using Action Bar Style Generator from the following link:-

(http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=test_style&compat=sherlock&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&backColor=9c0%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=fff%2C100&accentColor=ff0%2C100&cabBackColor=fff%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100)

Its perfectly doing what I want but now my problem is that I have no control on the font type/size/color of the title of Action Bar or even on the pop-up menu font. I just want to know how can I change the font size/type/color of my Action Bar from the styles that I have generated from the above link.

Please help me to sort this out, any help would be appreciable

Thanks in Advance.